# Cómo puedo recargar una página completa a determinada hora?

Tags: javascript, html5

Por ejemplo quisiera que se actualizara todos los días a las 7am y a las 9am.
Lo que quiero hacer es que hay dos emisoras online pero la emisora 1 solo la necesito de 7am a 9am eso lo hice haciendo un switch y quedó, pero cuando son las 9 y sigo en la emisora No.1 y si quiero que se reproduzca la emisora 2 tengo que recargar la página para que el javascript que hay y ahí si sirve. quiero quitarme ese problema de encima he intentado pero no encuentro como hacerlo.
Lo que quiero es que la página popUp que tengo que es de la emisora se recargue sola a las 7am y a las 9 am.

el código es el siguiente:

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="controlador.js">
   </script>
</body>
```

Gracias.

Comment: Para que tu pregunta no reciba negativos puedes editarla y agregar el codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La siguiente función te permitirá hacer eso que pides

```
function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds) {
    var now = new Date();
    var then = new Date();

    if(now.getHours() > hours ||
       (now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() > minutes) ||
        now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() == minutes && now.getSeconds() >= seconds) {
        then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
    }
    then.setHours(hours);
    then.setMinutes(minutes);
    then.setSeconds(seconds);

    var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
    setTimeout(function() {
       window.location.reload(true);
    }, timeout);
}
```

Y después la mandas a llamar

```
refreshAt(20,30,0); //Recargara la pagina a las 8:30PM
```

Recuerda que las horas son en formato 24 horas.